# Powershell Net-Cookie Expires

Tags: powershell, cookies, session-cookies, poshserver

We are using PoSH Server for our Webservices.

Does anyone know how to change / set the cookie expires in our script? This is how we currently try to do it:

```
$Response = $Context.Response
$Response.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding","gzip");
$Response.Headers.Add("Server","PoSH Server");
$Response.Headers.Add("X-Powered-By","Microsoft PowerShell");

$Cookie = New-Object Net.Cookie
$Cookie.Name = "SessionID"
$Cookie.Value = New-TimeStamp
$Cookie.Expires = now+10
$Response.AppendCookie($Cookie)
```

We also tried s.th. like: `$Cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10)` a.s.o.

The cookie is read in the following way:

```
$Cookies = $Request.Cookies["PoSHSessionID"];
```

The Cookie Expires (Lifetime) does not change. It´s always: Lifetime ends of session.

Comment: Where do you have this code? How is the $Response object created? Have you created a web server in PowerShell (and if so, why?) and are you thus adding this cookie to the response being sent to the browser navigating to your web server? Please add this information (preferably with more code context) to your question).

Comment: Hello Robert,

many thanks for your demand.
We are using PoShserver for our Webservices.

Here is the $Response:
$Response = $Context.Response
$Response.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding","gzip");
$Response.Headers.Add("Server","PoSH Server");
$Response.Headers.Add("X-Powered-By","Microsoft PowerShell");

The cookie is added like this: $Cookies = $Request.Cookies["PoSHSessionID"];

I hope you could help us. If you need further information, please tell me!

We are using Powershell as an webservice, because our web- and informationsystems are combined with SAP, Networktechnologies and more.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get it to set send along a value based on the date set to the `Expires` property, but it sends it as "max-age" instead of "expires" in the http header, which it would seem (from a quick internet search) isn't supported by at least IE of lower versions.

I'm not used to using the System.Net.HttpListenerResponse type (more used to the System.Web namespace used in ASP.NET) so I'm very likely missing something very obvious, but the only way I could get it to work as I wanted was to add the Set-Cookie header manually. An example on how to do this would be the following:

```
$Context.Response.Headers.Add("Set-Cookie", "myCookieName=myCookieValue; expires=Tue, 12-Jan-2016 01:14:40 GMT")
```

Do be aware, however, that you might have special characters in your cookie value which makes your Set-Cookie string invalid. A possible way to work around that could be to create the cookie value string using the System.Net.Cookie class, like you are doing, and just add the Set-Cookie header with the ToString() of the cookie with a manually appended expires value (ensure they are separated with a semicolon).

This does feel very much like an ugly work-around which shouldn't at all be necessary. I'm probably missing something, but on my virtual test machine (Win7, PowerShell 2.0, .NET 4.0, IE10, FF26) I couldn't get it to send Expires instead of Max-Age.

You can find a description of the format for the expires date at [the Wikipedia page about HTTP cookies under the header 'Expires and Max-Age'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age).

Comment: Hello Robert, 
many thanks for your perfect answer. 
The code works perfectly. 
You've been very helpful.